# How to install Yeoman on an Openshift Tomcat server

Tags: permissions, jenkins, installation, yeoman, openshift

I have a Java spring as server stack and with angularJS for the UI stack.

Part of the build process I need Jenkins to run `Grunt build` to optimize the UI before the build process starts.

I have tried to install Yeoman on the Jenkins instance but since I am not the administrator I am getting Access errors.

```
[\> npm install -g yo
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/var/lib/openshift/<ID>/.npm'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/var/lib/openshift/<ID>/.npm']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/var/lib/openshift/<ID>/.npm' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

Answer (score 3):

You're getting an access error because you're trying to do a global install - that's what the `-g` flag does. In other words, you're attempting to install yeoman in a system-wide location instead of locally, which requires root permissions.

Also, you shouldn't need to install yeoman in a production environment - yeoman just does app scaffolding. If you're using yeoman locally, it should have added grunt, and any grunt plugins you need, to the package.json file in your app. Make sure the package.json file is checked in, then as part of the build process, you can run `npm install`, then `grunt build`.

I'm not sure how Jenkins affects the build process, but normally, `npm install` will run automatically when you push a new commit to your OpenShift app.